# Cloudfront with Application Load Balancer returns 504

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I have a couple of docker containers running apis on 2 ec2 instances and an application load balancer between them and also a static website.

I'm trying to use the same url between them, so `myurl.com` brings me to the static website and `myurl.com/api/` hits the load balancer and eventually the apis.

The behaviour seems to be working correctly and Cloudfront is able to serve the static website ok but whenever I try the /api it returns 504.

My load balancer is internet facing and is in a security group allowing all traffic.

Comment: Have you enabled the ALB access logs? what are the behaviors/patterns? does a single request surpass timeout period?

Comment: Looks like it's not even hitting the ALB as the logs aren't getting populated and the monitoring is showing 0 hits.

Comment: How did you setup your CF distro and load balancer?